# How to prevent Ionic from navigating to the first page every time I refresh the page

Tags: angular, ionic3, deep-linking

I am using Ionic 3 + Angular and working on `Deeplinks`. 
I have configured following routes:

```
IonicModule.forRoot(
      App,
      { locationStrategy: 'hash'  },
      {
        links: [
          {
            component: ReportPage,
            segment: "report/:locationId/:itemId"
          },
          {
            component: HomePage,
            segment: "home/:locationId/:itemId"
          },
       ]
     }
 )
```

If I hit `home/1/2`  it redirects me to home page as expected.
If I hit `report/1/2`  it redirects me to report page as expected.

But problem comes when I hit `home/1/2` and control refresh the page it navigates me to the report page.

I tried to use the ionicPage segment but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you can set name in link object Like :

```
links: [

        {
          component: HomePage,
          segment: "home/:locationId/:itemId",
          name: 'home',
        },
         {
          component: ReportPage,
          name: 'report',
          segment: "report/:locationId/:itemId"
        },
     ]
```